# Setting default values in a Toplevel() window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code, and I want to initialize the widgets to a default value, but they insist on not doing so. I'm setting the StringVar() variables, I'm assigning them, and it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class popup():

    def __init__(self):
        edit_window=tk.Toplevel()

        works_checkbutton_val=[tk.IntVar()]*7
        start_time_combo_val=[tk.StringVar()]*7
        end_time_combo_val=[tk.StringVar()]*7

        datapoint=['Joe Blow','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','8 AM to 5 PM','3foobarIID']
        headings =['Employee Name','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

        for row in range(1,len(datapoint)-1):
            ttk.Label(edit_window, text=headings[row]).grid(row=row+1, column=0, sticky='e', pady=((7.5,0),(7.5,7.5))[row==len(datapoint)-2], padx=5)

            ttk.Label(edit_window, text=headings[0]).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e', pady=(7.5,0), padx=5)
            employee_name_entry = ttk.Entry(edit_window)
            employee_name_entry.insert(0, datapoint[0])
            employee_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=(7.5,0), padx=5, sticky='ew')

        works_checkbutton=[]
        start_time_combo=[]
        end_time_combo=[]
        for row in range(1,len(datapoint)-1):
            split_time=datapoint[row].split(' to ')
            if len(split_time)==1:
                works_checkbutton_val[row-1].set(0)
                start_time_combo_val[row-1].set('0 AM')
                end_time_combo_val[row-1].set('0 AM')
            else:
                works_checkbutton_val[row-1].set(1)
                start_time_combo_val[row-1].set(split_time[0])
                end_time_combo_val[row-1].set(split_time[1])

            works_checkbutton.append(ttk.Checkbutton(edit_window, variable = works_checkbutton_val[row-1]))
            works_checkbutton[row-1].grid(row=row+1, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=(0,(0,7.5))[row==len(datapoint)-2], sticky='s')

            start_time_combo.append(ttk.Combobox(edit_window, values=["%s AM"%(x+1) for x in range(12)] + ["%s PM"%(x+1) for x in range(12)],textvariable=start_time_combo_val[row-1]))
            start_time_combo[row-1].grid(row=row+1, column=4, pady=((7.5,0),(7.5,7.5))[row==len(datapoint)-2], padx=5)

            end_time_combo.append(ttk.Combobox(edit_window, values=["%s AM"%(x+1) for x in range(12)] + ["%s PM"%(x+1) for x in range(12)],textvariable=end_time_combo_val[row-1]))
            end_time_combo[row-1].grid(row=row+1, column=3, pady=((7.5,0),(7.5,7.5))[row==len(datapoint)-2], padx=5)


main_window=tk.Tk()
b1 = ttk.Button(main_window,text='here',command=lambda:popup())
b1.pack()
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need `[tk.IntVar() for x in range(7)]`, `[tk.StringVar() for x in range(7)]`

Comment: Thanks, that solved another problem I had with all the options being linked. But I'm still not getting a value initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IntVar`, `StringVar` variables are stored in local variables. They will be gone once the `popup` function returns.

You need to keep them (at least until the Toplevel is valid). For example, following lines save the variables as `edit_window`'s instance variables so that they will survive while the `edit_window` toplevel is valid.

```
edit_window.vals1 = works_checkbutton_val = [tk.IntVar() for i in range(7)]
edit_window.vals2 = start_time_combo_val = [tk.StringVar() for i in range(7)]
edit_window.vals3 = end_time_combo_val = [tk.StringVar() for i in range(7)]
```